# Function name followed by assignment operator

Tags: ruby, attr-accessor

What does the following function definition mean? Why is there an assignment operator in the function name?

```
def func=(param)
  @param = param
end
```

Comment: I do believe it’s a setter for a property. Ish.

Comment: Hint: Why is there a `z` in `def baz(param)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does the following function definition mean?

They are called *writer* method in Ruby.

> Why there is an assignment operator in the function name?

It adds *sugar* in your syntax.

While you have a method as

```
def func=(param)
  @param = param
end
```

You can call it as *normal assignment*

```
ob.func = 12 # same as obj.func(12)
```

Comment: `func = 12` creates a local variable `func`.

Answer (score 2):

That's a setter method in Ruby.  It allows you to do `model.func = 'some value'`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an [**Assignment Method**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Assignment+Methods). It enables you to define methods that behaves like assignment:

```
class C
  def value=(value)
    @value = value
  end
end

c = C.new
c.value = 42
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
class Check
  attr_accessor :c_equals
  def c_equals=(some value)
    @c_equals = some_value
  end
  def c_equals
    @c_equals
  end
end

c = Check.new
c.c_equals = 'Hello World'
c.c_equals
```

Adding a method name with an equals sign is called when you do an assignment operation via that method. You can see in the example above that when you call `c.c_equals="hello world"`, the function `c_equals=()` is called.